# play framework - what is the proper way to return list of data?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to the reactive/observables concept.

I've defined a route for getting `Products` like this:

`GET    /products   controllers.ProductController.findProducts`

and the implementation in the controller:

```scala
def findProducts() = secured.async { implicit request =>
  productDao.find()
    .map(products => Ok(Json.toJson(products)))
    // products: List[Product]  
    .recover(errHandler)
}
```

Then, on the client-side, I'm making the call and subscribing to it like this:

```typescript
let sub = this.find()
  .subscribe(
    products => {
      this.products = products;
      this.productsBehaviorSubject.next( this.products );
      if (!!sub)
        sub.unsubscribe();
    },
    error => console.log("Error fetching units: " + error)
  );
```

As soon as I get the data, I unsubscribe from it. (basically using it like Promises).
So I wonder, if this is the right way to do it. Instead of returning `List[Product]` in one single response, should I be returning in several responses??

```scala
def findProducts() = secured.async { implicit request =>
  productDao.find()
    .map(products => {
      products.map(p => Ok(Json.toJson(p))) // haven't tried this yet
    })
    // products: List[Product]  
    .recover(errHandler)
}
```

then on the client side .. maybe .:

```typescript
this.find()
  .take( 50 )
  .subscribe(
    product => {
      this.products.push( product )
    },
    error => console.log("Error fetching units: " + error),
    () => this.productsBehaviorSubject.next( this.products )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is correct, you will notice that the `secured.async` expects the code block to return `Future[Result]`. So if you try to map over the products then the signature will be `Future[Seq[Result]]` which will give you a compilation error.

Also in my experience, returning the full list in a single response is the standard way to code.